# CSET instruction of ARMV8 instruction set

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

How the CSET instruction of ARM architecture works?It compares the standard condition check on which registers?Please help.

Answer (score 7):

Per the [ARMv8 ISA](http://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/41836-102-1-229511/ARM.Reference_Manual.pdf):

> `CSET Wd, cond`
>
> Conditional Set: Wd = if cond then 1 else 0.

Meaning the instruction performs a Conditional Set instruction. What is a Conditional Set instruction?

> Conditional set: conditionally select between 0 and 1 or -1, for example to materialize the condition flags as a Boolean value or mask in a general register.

You can translate this into a simple ternary operation: `Wd = cond ? 1 : 0`. So, if `cond` is `true`, `Wd = 1`. Otherwise, `Wd = 0`.

What is *cond*?

> *cond* - A standard ARM condition EQ, NE, CS|HS, CC|LO, MI, PL, VS, VC, HI, LS, GE, LT, GT, LE, AL or NV with the same meanings as in AArch32. Note that although AL and NV represent different
> encodings, as in AArch32 they are both interpreted as the “always true” condition. Unless stated AArch64 instructions do not set or use the condition flags, but those that do set all of the condition flags. If used in a pseudo-code expression this symbol represents a Boolean whose value is the truth of the specified condition test.

Comment: conditions like LT and GT are performed on which registers?Are they performed on operands?

Comment: Just like anything else conditional, the condition is evaluated against the condition flags in PSTATE, as set by a previous comparison (or other flag-setting) instruction.

Comment: I'm looking at a disassembly from objdump that is instrumented with a fair number of *`cset    x3, hi  // hi = pmore`*.

Answer (score 6):

```
int yesOrNo(int value) {
    return value != 0;
}
```

Intel:

```
   0:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   2:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
   4:   0f 95 c0                setne  %al
   7:   c3                      retq
```

arm in thumb mode:

```
   0:   1e43            subs    r3, r0, #1
   2:   4198            sbcs    r0, r3
   4:   4770            bx      lr
```

arm in arm mode:

```
   0:   e2900000        adds    r0, r0, #0
   4:   13a00001        movne   r0, #1
   8:   e12fff1e        bx      lr
```

aarch64:

```
   0:   6b1f001f        cmp     w0, wzr
   4:   1a9f07e0        cset    w0, ne
   8:   d65f03c0        ret
```

which is a great deal more transparent, and in any case nicer than any of the above